# Count occurrences within subgroup using R

Tags: r, count

I use the mtcars dataset as an example

```
>head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl  disp   hp  drat    wt   qsec  vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6   160  110  3.90  2.620  16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6   160  110  3.90  2.875  17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4   108   93  3.85  2.320  18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6   258  110  3.08  3.215  19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8   360  175  3.15  3.440  17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6   225  105  2.76  3.460  20.22  1  0    3    1
```

I would like to count the number of 8-cylinder cars that do NOT have 3 'gears'. Sorry for this very basic question. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with(mtcars, sum(cyl == 8 & gear != 3))
#[1] 2
```

We can compare the values and create a logical vector for the condition we want and count the number of `TRUE` values using `sum`.

We can use the same comparison to subset the rows using `subset` or `filter` from `dplyr`

```
subset(mtcars, cyl == 8 & gear != 3)

#                mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Ford Pantera L 15.8   8  351 264 4.22 3.17 14.5  0  1    5    4
#Maserati Bora  15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.6  0  1    5    8
```

and then count rows

```
nrow(subset(mtcars, cyl == 8 & gear != 3))
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Thank you, Ronak. That is terrific.

Comment: This worked perfectly on the mtcars dataset, so it seemed so simple to apply this to my dataset to count the number of samples that are not NA within my subset of interest, but somehow that does not work. Might you have a suggestion? Maybe using subset and is.na? I tried: count(mtcars$cyl == 8)-sum(is.na(subset(mtcars$gear == 3))), but unfortunately, that did not work. Thank you.

Comment: @SylviaRodriguez use the same format as shown in first example using `sum`. Try `with(your_df, sum(column_name1 == cond & !is.na(column_name2)))` where `your_df` is your dataframe name, `column_name1` is column name of subset and `column_name2` is the column to count `NA`s from.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `dplyr::filter` as:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(mtcars, cyl == 8 & gear != 3)
```

Comment: Thank you, Sonny. That is terrific.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by first transforming the row names into columns, then filtering what you are looking for, and pipe it into `count()`

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tibble)

mtcars %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
  dplyr::filter(cyl == 8 & gear != 3) %>% 
  dplyr::count(rowname)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   rowname            n
#>   <chr>          <int>
#> 1 Ford Pantera L     1
#> 2 Maserati Bora      1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, FMM. That is terrific.

Answer (score 1):

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mtcars)[cyl == 8 & gear != 3]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, akrun. I had follow-up problem, see above under @ronakshah. He kindly solved that for me too.

Comment: @SylviaRodriguez  If you want the number of rows, then `setDT(mtcars)[, sum(cyl== 8 & gear !=3)]`